How can I get the CPU temperature in Rust?
How can I get the temperature of a PC's CPU in Rust?
I ultimately want to get the temperature (in celsius) every five minutes and log it to the console.
I am targeting Windows 10 20H2 and have Rust version 1.75.0.

The sys-info crate allows you to retrieve various system information(including the CPU’s temperature I think)
get_temperature()
